# How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number by prepending 0?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert a one digit double value, for example, 1.27 to 01.27.

And if the number is 12.27 then it should be 12.27 itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


final formatter = new NumberFormat('00.00');
print(formatter.format(1.27));
```

result : 01.27

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this might do for you:

```
void main() {
  print((1.27).toString().padLeft(2, '0'));
  print((12.27).toString().padLeft(2, '0'));
}
```